# Simple Basketball Motion Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

What happens: When I press space button the ball moves up and stops; when press again the ball moves down.

What I need: When I press space button the ball should move up then move down!

I want to some how repeat this function twice with one click ... Its looks simple; I tried to loop twice upon the press of the space button, but it doesn't work as I expected. Any suggestions?

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var basketball = document.getElementById('basketball');

var x = 0;
var y = 0;


var counter = 0;
var inc = Math.PI / 100  ;



body.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var ek = e.which; 
    if(ek==32){
        
            for( var i = 0; i<=1 ;i+=0.01){
                x+=i;
                y+= Math.sin( counter );
                counter+=inc;

                basketball.style.left=x;
                basketball.style.bottom=y; 
            }    
    }
});
```

```css
*
{
    transition: all 1s;
}

#basketball
{
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>                
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_style.css">        
        <title>Basket</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">       
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/basketball-ball-transparent-checkered-background-realistic-vector-illustration-91566559.jpg" id="basketball">
        
        
        <script src="js/mine.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (the function calls itself):

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var basketball = document.getElementById('basketball');

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var counter = 0;
var inc = Math.PI / 100  ;

function bounce(e, norecall){
    var ek = e.which; 
    console.log('keydown');
    if(ek==32){
        
        for( var i = 0; i<=1 ;i+=0.01){
            x+=i;
            y+= Math.sin( counter );
            counter+=inc;

            basketball.style.left=x;
            basketball.style.bottom=y; 
        }
            
    }

    if (!norecall) { //only runs the first time (when norecall == undefined)
        bounce(e, true)
    }

}

body.addEventListener('keydown',bounce); //call bounce on keypress
```

```css
*
{
    transition: all 1s;
}

#basketball
{
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>                
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_style.css">        
        <title>Basket</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">       
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/basketball-ball-transparent-checkered-background-realistic-vector-illustration-91566559.jpg" id="basketball">
        
        
        <script src="js/mine.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What this does is the function `bounce` gets called with norecall being `undefined`. `!norecall` is then `true`, so the function calls itself, this time with `norecall` being `true`, so the function doesn’t get called again, therefore mimicing the mouse being pressed twice, which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need for loops and stuff, you can just use css and add a class that changes the `bottom` from 0, and use `setTimeout` to remove it after some time (you need to click on the example so it will get the focus and the key events).

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var basketball = document.getElementById('basketball');


body.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
   basketball.classList.add('up');
   setTimeout(function(){
      basketball.classList.remove('up'); 
   }, 300);
});
```

```css
#basketball
{
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10;
}

#basketball.up {
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>                
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_style.css">        
        <title>Basket</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">       
        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/basketball-ball-transparent-checkered-background-realistic-vector-illustration-91566559.jpg" id="basketball">                        
        <script src="js/mine.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```